# Can react in-browser load external libraries?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I load react in the browser I don't have the ability to "npm install" a library and then include it with my react code with:

```
var somelibrary = require('somelibrary');
```

I was wondering how I'd do it in the browser is it as simple as just running a source file after I load react. like

```
<script src="somereactlibrary.js"></script>
```

Or do libraries have a bunch of files/dependencies and it won't be as easy as that? (What if the library is just one file.. is it technically possible?)

This is code from reactjs.org to have react in the browser:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Hello World</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

    <!-- Don't use this in production: -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="text/babel">

      ReactDOM.render(
        <h1>Hello, world!</h1>,
        document.getElementById('root')
      );

    </script>
    <!--
      Note: this page is a great way to try React but it's not suitable for production.
      It slowly compiles JSX with Babel in the browser and uses a large development build of React.

      Read this section for a production-ready setup with JSX:
      http://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html#add-jsx-to-a-project

      In a larger project, you can use an integrated toolchain that includes JSX instead:
      http://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html

      You can also use React without JSX, in which case you can remove Babel:
      https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-jsx.html
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can load anything you want via a script tag, nothing to do with React. Dependency management will be problematic, which is why various bundling mechanisms exist.

Comment: @DaveNewton thanks, what if I mainly create my own components, would it still be a problem? or what are some examples libraries that I need that I wouldn't be able to load this way. the reason why I'm doing it this way is for a small quick project that I'd rather not deal with building/webpack etc.

Comment: If there are no dependencies, there are no dependencies. You can load *any* library this way--it's just JS. Personally I don't think messing around w/ in-browser React is worth it: you could have had everything running between the time you first asked and now, e.g., via create-react-app.

Comment: @DaveNewton yeah.. I've been using create-react-app. But the size of it (hundreds of mb) and build step seems a bit too much for really small utilities I create. for big projects cra is definitely useful.

Comment: @foreyez I like [microbundle](https://github.com/developit/microbundle) for using a modern developing environment which can build for all targets. Might be worth checking out.

Comment: Hundreds of megabytes? You're doing something wrong; create-react-app deploys like 100-150K of JS. The build step consists entirely of "yarn build". *shrug* There are other solutions, but whether you do it this way or any other, you're going to end up deploying a bunch of JS (and additional JS if you're compiling in the browser).

Comment: @DaveNewton I meant the node_modules folder under the create-react-app dir.

Comment: @foreyez But... #1, so what? They're not deployed--much of it is what allows ES6 and all the transformations that let JS not suck. #2, if you're doing anything of any complexity you'll need some of it anyway, but you'll have to manage the dependencies by hand (which is hard), etc. I mean, I'm not saying don't do it, I'm just saying it's rarely worth it. There's a reason such a thing exists--because writing modern JS is fraught with difficulties.

Answer (score 0):

To render React in the browser you need the `react` and `react-dom` libraries. Other libraries can be loaded as separate script tags like you say, if you don't have access to a build step that can bundle all your code together.

**Example**

```js
ReactDOM.render(
  React.createElement('div', {}, moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD')),
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/moment@2.22.2/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: shouldn't the library be included after the react/react-dom? maybe not moment, but a library that depends on react

Comment: @foreyez Yes, you're right. That's what becomes so hairy if you have no sort of build step. You need to make sure that potential dependencies of other libraries are loaded manually first.